# How can I find the file name referenced by a NFS packet?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have several Linux clients mounting a NFS volume from a Linux server. The server had an issue and it was rebooted.

Some of the clients are now hammering the server with  request like:

```
224 getattr fh 0,0/22
```

and the server is replying with:

```
reply ok 52 getattr ERROR: unk 10025
```

But this is going on and on.

I think I'm hitting a bug described here:
http://linux-nfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/WEhJVdG5/nfs-loop-on-3-4-39

I would like to know if there is a way to trace the original filename the client is trying to use.

Thanks!